# How to install ceiling fan in this unique situation

Tags: ceiling-fan, sunroom

I’ve come across a ceiling fan that was installed rather shockingly, and I’m tasked to replace it with a new one. But I want to install the new one using more up to date standards. The ceiling fan was wobbly and I think you’ll understand why when you see the photo. I was a little shocked when I saw this:

[image]

Apparently this has been working for multiple years like this. From what I can gather there is no receptacle above the fan and the wiring is just snaked through underneath the trim siding material that sits on a 2x4 or 2x6 spanning the ceiling.

The top canopy of the unit isn’t fully flush with the top spanning “joist” (or whatever that is structurally) whatsoever and hangs over on each side by a few inches. If you look closely, the middle portion of the canopy is attached less than what isn’t attached. I wasn’t able to remove the canopy to see how it’s attached but would assume something goofy.

This is inside a cheap aluminum sunroom. So I don’t have the luxury of drywall and joists to install an expected box between joists. I’m looking for any guidance, suggestions, or research tips on how to effectively install a new ceiling fan that I can be proud of, but more importantly not worry about it murdering anyone or wobbling all day.

Comment: Not a full answer as I am not touching the mounting portion: the wobble has nothing to do with how it's mounted. The wobble is all about the balance of the blades. That fan, like most ceiling fans, is mounted using a ball at the top of the downrod so it can pivot and wobble if it's out of balance. Try leveling and balancing it to eliminate the wobble.

Comment: I agree with @KMJ about the wobble. You'll have to remove the canopy to assess the strength of the mounting to the ridge beam, which may be solid or may require a re-do. The fan mounting in my dining room also looks cheesy, but the mounting bracket (under the canopy) is very firmly mounted to the wood above, and quite secure.

Comment: As to the mounting, just because the decorative cover extends past the mounting "surface" that doesn't necessarily mean the install is sketch.  The actual fan mount is in all likelihood much smaller than that.

Comment: Wobble isn't just about blade balance. I've fixed comically wobbly fans by tightening the set screws in the hanging hardware--the ball socket and the downrod connection. They need to be rigid because no fan is perfectly balanced.

Comment: I'm not sure this question is answerable without more insight into the roof construction. I'd want to add a plate spanning the ridge to allow proper mounting. I'd also want to protect the cable wiring, but that's all hidden from us. Please update with more information.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are trying to find a way to install the fan to be more aestheticly pleasing instead of the fan looking like it's hanging by threads.
What comes to my mind is to either
A. bore into the beam with a door knob bit or something round to a depth that will allow the fan crown to sit flush. You might have to drill another hole for the wiring to be tucked into. OR
B. Manufacture extensions and attach them to the sides of the beam with 45° holes for screws. A 2 x ? SANDWICH around the support beam. The area will end up a square, round or whichever shape you prefer, then once attached there will be a nice sturdy area to attach the fan crown. You might also consider drilling a canal across the top for wiring.
Additionally, balance the fan by tightening all nuts, neck bolts and light fixtures BEFORE installing to check for wobbling or noise.
My little trick is to apply just a tad of Loctite as each piece is added. That helps to keep nuts in place. If you haven't completed this project already, good luck. Oh ya there's one other alternative, install a regular non-moving light and invest in a good cooling unit, new windows or a heavier duty floor fan. Just saying... That is an option too. Post a pic of your finished project.

Comment: Could you please break up your text, the wall of text is hard to read.